# pinescript crossover price with SMA does not seem to be working

Tags: pine-script

I want to check if the price crossed over the 200 SMA for more than a given amount of candles (customizable).  If true i want it to open a long (i have other conditions i need to add later but i noticed my code is already not working here).  It opens longs over the complete chart even when the price is not over the 200SMA.

this is what i have:

```
SMA200  = sma(close, 200)
//PRICE OVER EMA CHECKS
TrendBarsCount = input(5, "Price closes needed above/below 200 MA", minval=1)
emaCrossOver = crossover(close, SMA200)
var emaLongCondition = false
if barssince(emaCrossOver) >= TrendBarsCount
    emaLongCondition := true
strategy.entry("Open Long", strategy.long, when = emaLongCondition)
```

it just doesn't seem to care about the SMA at all, what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Checks if a candle closes above 200 SMA, then waits 5 candles to open a long.

```
SMA200  = sma(close, 200)

TrendBarsCount = input(5, "Price closes needed above/below 200 MA", minval=1)
emaCrossOver = crossover(close, SMA200)
longCondition = barssince(emaCrossOver) == TrendBarsCount

if longCondition
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
```